# Coupon code isn't working

Tags: magento-1.7, coupon, coupon-codes

I have a problem with coupon codes in magento.

I created a lot of coupons for testing in all possible ways and nothing is working.

None of them work, and the same error (when the customer enters the coupon code) is displayed every time... The coupon "coupon_name" is not valid.

**EDIT:**

Below some pics with the coupon rule:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add screenshots of your coupon config.

Comment: Not sure exactly, but could it be that your configuration only works if the customer is logged in? "Uses per customer" set to "2" might cause this.

Comment: I mimicked these settings on my store, and it seemed to work without any issue. In response to @LouisBataillard customer login status shouldn't affect the coupon as all customer types are selected in the config, including NOT LOGGED IN. In my own testing, I set Uses per customer to 2, and it didn't negatively affect the usability. I know this doesn't particularly answer the question, but it at least eliminates some concerns.

Comment: Can u add max products discount to more than 0.

Comment: I set to "2" in "Uses per customer" and still doesn't work. It's really strange, because the other rules works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could install this module: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Hackathon_PromoCodeMessages (disclaimer: I wrote this module). This will give you more accurate error messages. You could even just install it to determine what is wrong, and then uninstall it :)

Comment: Thank you @Laura.. I'm installing the module now, later I bring news

Comment: @erick.bruno accept the answer if it worked for you.